# Camel: using unmarshal().tidyMarkup() from multiple threads

Tags: apache-camel, tidy

It's apparently thread safe. However, can anyone tell me if it's locked with single instance of TidyMarkupDataFormat or separate instances are created for separate threads?
I mean do we have multiple parsers (one per one thread) or a single parser shared among all threads.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the code of TidyMarkupDataFormat, it creates parer per unmarshalrequest.
So I think it should be thread safe, as no parer is shared in different threads.

Comment: I see some locking inside TidyMarkupDataFormat in multithreaded app. I need to investigate.